# String.split("(?<=\\G..)") splits different on windows and android

Tags: java, android, string

i'm starting with android studio and app developing! I have a java code that works fine on my windows 8.1 PC but when i copy the code into my app one certain part doesn't work properly... I will explain it to you:

I'm using a split command to split a String into pieces of 2 characters. The regex i use is the following:

```
Text.split("(?<=\\G..)");
```

On pc it works perfect! Example:

The String: `cef9c2....`
-> `"ce" + "f9" + "c2" + ".." + ".."`

but the debugging on Android shows what the same code does to the String:

The String: `cef9c2....` 
-> `"ce" + "f9c2...."`

Could anybody please help me? That would be nice :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily define a function to do this yourself, hence being sure it will also work on android.

```
public String[] splitInSubstrings (String str, int len) {
    int siz = (int)Math.ceil((double)str.length() / (double) len);
    String[] res = new String[siz];
    int idx = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        int end_idx = ((idx + len) >= str.length()) ? str.length() : (idx + len);
        res[i] = str.substring(idx, end_idx); 
        idx += len;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Oh well thanks a lot for the quick answer! I will try it! Thanks for writing for me cuz i'm new to this :)

Answer (score 1):

The Android Regex implementation differs from the java "standard". So that might be reason for your problem.

> The regular expression implementation used in Android is provided by ICU. The notation for the regular expressions is mostly a superset of those used in other Java language implementations. This means that existing applications will normally work as expected, but in rare cases Android may accept a regular expression that is not accepted by other implementations. In some cases, Android will recognize that a regular expression is a simple special case that can be handled more efficiently. This is true of both the convenience methods in String and the methods in Pattern.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

I suggest that you rethink your regex pattern according to the explaination given under the link above.